# CSS Effects, Hover over a div Container and all the other div Containers lower the opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, effects

I am working on a Website where I created 5 different Blocks with a div container. Now I added a CSS effect which makes the div container pop up if you hover over it.

```
.site-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 18%;
    height: 345px;
    background-color: #23253b;
    margin: 8px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.site-block:hover {
    transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

HTML for 1 Block

```
    <div class="site-block">
                    <div class="site-logo">
                        <img src="img/sites/csgoempire-logo.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bonus">
                        <p>Get a free case!</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="deposit-methods">
                        <img src="img/deposit-methods/btc-deposit.png" alt="G2A" />
                        <img src="img/deposit-methods/eth-deposit.png" alt="CSGO" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="code">
                        <a>Primatcodes</a>
                        <img src="img/copy.png" alt="CSGO" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="site-url">
                        <a href="https://daddyskins.com/promo-code/Primatcodes">Claim
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now I want to add another effect which should blur out all the other blocks. So bassicaly if I hover over a block I want that block to pop out and have a opacity of 1 and the other 4 should lower their opacity to 0.2. Is that possible with CSS or Javascript? and if yes HOW

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: can you provide HTML of all those divs?

Comment: Added the HTML for 1 Block they are all the same

Comment: All 5 blocks have same classes?

Comment: yes they are all the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there is a CSS way, but here is a javascript native way using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```css
.container {
display:flex;
}

.site-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 18%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #23253b;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #FFF;
}


.site-block:hover {
  transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="site-block">
   <p>AAA</p>
  </div>
  <div class="site-block"><p>AAA</p></div>
  <div class="site-block"><p>AAA</p></div>
  <div class="site-block"><p>AAA</p></div>
</div>
<!-- first try it like this, then move it to file, just make sure  your HTML above js tag ☝️and its before </body> -->
<script>
const siteBox = document.querySelectorAll('.site-block');

siteBox.forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {

    siteBox.forEach((box) => {
      if(event.target !== box) {
        //box.style.opacity = 0.2;
        box.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(35, 37, 59, 0.2)';
        box.style.color = '#000';
      }
    });
    event.target.opacity = 1;
  });
  
  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    siteBox.forEach((otherBox) => {
      otherBox.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(35, 37, 59)';
      otherBox.style.color = '#FFF';
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nice way of doing it. I was struggling with setting other ones to lower opacity.

Comment: Ok it somehow does not work for me, do I have to add the opacity of the container like this <div class="site-block" style="opacity: 1;"> ? or is it done automatically with the js script? Because if I hover over a Block nothing happens

Comment: or is the linking of the javascript file wrong ? <link href="js/script.js">

Comment: where did you put the javascript? try adding it just before </body> (body closing tag).

Comment: javascript tags should be like this `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` just make sure to put it at the end of the `<body>` tag and make sure the path is right.

Comment: I added in the head what do you mean with at the end of the body tag

Comment: Check [this out](https://mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-link-an-external-javascript-file/). As you will see, it is just before `</body>`

Comment: @NoobOnStack. I updated my answer with the script tag included in the HTML.

Comment: Damn you are a big help it work but now I have the problem, that all the other containers in the site-block div lower their opacity too when the mouse is on one of them and not exactly on the site-block div

Comment: can you make a fiddle? that would be better to work on: https://jsfiddle.net/ just reproduce the issue there and I will do my best to help :) its easier that way to spot the issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/NoobOnFiddle/bw4dy9kv/3/ Hope this link works, looks a bit messy since all the pictures are not loading but now you can see if you hover over the text and the other stuff everything lowers the opacity

Comment: @ROOT True, if you hover on one of div's children, whole div will go to 0.2 opacity too.

Comment: @NoobOnStack, do you mean that the inner divs should not have opacity? then maybe you should use [`rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#transparent) background color for this?

Comment: only the inner divs of the div that is getting hovered over should not lower the opacity

Comment: @NoobOnStack, I think I got it, I just fixed it by changing events here, used `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead. fixed in the snippet and here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/tvxpyd7h/3/

Comment: wow your a beast! Thank you very much